Amplitude modulation problems
I am trying to do amplitude modulation using a diode, but my circuit will not work. This is the circuit I am using:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I don't know why this won't work as I have found other circuits online with a similar design.
My questions are:

Why wont this circuit work?
Do you know a better way to do amplitude modulation with a crystal oscillator?

The circuit below is one that I have built but I am trying to use a crystal oscilator.


circuits online with a similar design ... please show some

I just edited to show the online design. I built that circuit but took out Rsum and Rf for 1MHz and it worked

A classic amplitude modulator is the diode bridge one as in the figure:


Would this circuit work for a higher frequency carrier wave (25MHz)?

Components suitable for working at this frequency are necessary, the band pass filter must be centered on the carrier and have a band double that of the modulating signal.

Is there a max frequency for diodes?

You can see this from the device datasheets.

If you did not make these images yourself, you should credit the source where you got them by posting links to those sources in your answer.

@Math   The circuit design was created by me using PAINT, but the diagram can be found in many telecommunications texts.


That's not a crystal oscillator.

I can't think of a reason why that circuit SHOULD work.

Where on earth did you find it?



I just edited the question to show where I got the idea for.

@MarcusMarchese, I don't see any link to where you got the circuit from.


I can.  It is a stripped-down version of a ring modulator.  Varying the current through a diode makes it appear as a varying resistance.  If a low amplitude carrier is riding on a higher amplitude modulating signal, the diode acts as the series leg of a 2-element attenuator, with Rf as the shunt leg.  This was done in broadcast audio processing stuff in the 60's by CBS Labs, called a vario-losser.  Ward used it as an AGC circuit in their station intercom.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_modulation


A more sophisticated AM modulator which can be found in various texts on the subject is the following which however needs to be sized according to the applicant's requirements and this is a fairly difficult task for those who do not have much experience:

